# How to redirect sequence of numbers to parallel in bash

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I wanted to parallelize curl requests and i used the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49360294/running-a-loop-bash-curl-script-with-gnu-parallel).
The input i want to use is a sequence of numbers generated using `seq` but the redirection keeps giving me errors like ambiguous input.

Here is the code:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

brx() {
  num="$1"
  curl -s "https://www.example.com/$num"
}
export -f brx

while true; do
  parallel -j10 brx < $(seq 1 100)
done
```

I tried with < `seq 1 100` but that didn't work either. Anyone know how i could get around this one?

Comment: `seq 1 100 | parallel -j10 brx`

Comment: @markp-fuso That's better than my answer - you should add it and get my vote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Small tweak to OP's current code:

```
# as a pseduto file descriptor

parallel -j10 brx < <(seq 1 100)
```

Alternatively:

```
# as a 'here' string

parallel -j10 brx <<< $(seq 1 100)
```

Comment: This is better than my answer - it is nearer to OP's attempt and also can provide an unlimited number of values on `stdin` whereas mine is limited by length of ARGMAX.

Answer (score 1):

Try with bash *brace expansion*:

```
parallel echo ::: {1..100}
```

Or:

```
parallel echo ::: $(seq 1 100)
```